# Model is not fully loaded out of DB after save from EF-Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a EF-Core Code-First apporach. Im Saving a HolderModel into a Database which contains a ID and a List of Models.

On Saving everything works fine. The Struktur is correct and all data is in the Database. But if i load the data back into my code, the List of Models is gone.

Im a bit confused as usally EF did everything by him self.
Am i missing something for EF-Core ?

Here is the codesnippet:

DB-Context:

```
    public DbSet<FinancialStateHolderModel> States { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseSqlServer(
            @"Server=.\;Database=Stock;User Id=dbuser;Password=dbuser");
        builder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true);
    }
```

HolderModel:

```
    public class FinancialStateHolderModel
{
    [Key]
    public String Symbol { get; set; }


    public List<FinancialStatementModel> Financials { get; set; }
}
```

Models:

```
public class FinancialStatementModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please show us how you're loading the model. It looks like you're not loading the related entities. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Comment: Perfect please post it as answer. You need to in addation load it explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) in Entity Framework.

You're looking for

> Eager loading - the related data is loaded from the database as part
>   of the initial query

In your case(example not exact syntax because I don't know what your call looks like)

should be `context.FinancialStateHolders.Include(x=> x.FinancialStatements)`

Comment: FinancialStateHolders is States. So, the statement is something like context.States.Include(s => s.Financials)